# Subscribing to UIButton tap in a UICollectionViewCell in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, frp, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift, trying to wrap my head around it.  I was having trouble getting a UIButton in a cell to show a UIAlertController when it's pressed.

```
private func setupCellConfiguration() {
        bookListViewModel.data
            .bindTo(collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: BookListCell.Identifier, cellType: BookListCell.self)) { [unowned self] (row, element, cell) in
                cell.configureForBook(book: element)
                cell.moreButton.rx.tap.subscribe { [weak self] in
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {(action) in
                        self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                    let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action) in

                    }
                    alertController.addAction(destroyAction)
                    self?.present(alertController, animated: true)
                }
                .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
 }
```

Nothing happens when it's pressed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you used the XCode debugger to double check if self was not nil, and if the alert controller was successfully instantiated? That way you can try to isolate where the problem is (is it an Rx issue, or is it a referencing issue).

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer to assign cell button action on its subclass. The problem is I think every cell should have it's own disposeBag and it should reinitialize every time it is reused.

Example: Haven't tested on code, if there's any problem let me know

```
private func setupCellConfiguration() {
bookListViewModel.data
    .bindTo(collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: BookListCell.Identifier, cellType: BookListCell.self)) { [unowned self] (row, element, cell) in

        cell.delegate = self
        cell.configureForBook(book: element)
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}

// Your Cell Class
var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
var delegate: UIViewController?

func configureForBook(book: Book) {

    self.moreButton.rx.tap.subscribe { [unowned self] in

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {(action) in
        self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action) in

    }
    alertController.addAction(destroyAction)
    self.delegate?.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
    .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
   disposeBag = DisposeBag()
}
```